# How to set constant property in code behind to view using xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have one view controller in Xamarin form, In that I have created one button and view assigned a height and width for view. In application execution I have hide the view using constant=-100(width). while click the button i want to show the view using Constant=0. But its not working showed error like UIView does not contain a definition for 'Constant' and no extension method 'Constant' accepting a first argument of type UIView could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Default constant is - 190 because of sidebar view.partial void Btnsidemenu_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            sidemenu.constant=0;            
          
        }

Answer (score 0):

[Constant](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.NSLayoutConstraint.Constant/) is not a property of a control, It's a property of [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.NSLayoutConstraint/).

> I have one view controller in Xamarin form

I'm confused about whether you are working on Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS? UIViewController and UIView are components of Xamarin.iOS.

If you want to change the `UIView`'s Width Constraint in Xamarin.iOS using code behind, you can try:

```
foreach(NSLayoutConstraint constraint in sidemenu.Constraints)
{
    if (constraint.FirstItem == sidemenu && constraint.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Width)
    {
        constraint.Constant = 190;
        break;
    }
}
```

Moreover if you are using Storyboard, you can reference the sidemenu's Width Constraint to the corresponding `UIViewController` as an outlet. Then Modify it:

```
// WidthConstraint is an outlet of sidemenu's width constraint
WidthConstraint.Constant = 190;
```

Comment: Not working the above code. I have to add and remove the constant property value which I have give the view controller.

Comment: Can you share some code about your ViewController and your constraints?

Comment: In design page i have declare the layout constraint value is -190. 190 is my view width size. I need while clicking the button in the page view layout constraint value to change as 0.

Comment: How many constraints you will get from `sidemenu.Constraints`?

Comment: only one from leading constraints in Sidemenu view

Comment: Then you just miss some constraints when you set at first. It should contain width and height constraints.